# display date inputs with php and html

Tags: php, html

I want to display the value of two inputs with date type but it didn't work. 
Here is my code,

```
    <html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
    <link rel ="stylesheet" href="style_wbr.css"/>
    <title>PORTAIL</title>
</head>
<body>

<br></br>
<br></br>
<br></br>
  <form method = "post" action = "#">
   <div id="date">
  <input type="date" id="date_deb_filtre" name="Date_de_debut" />
  <input type="date" id="date_fin_filtre" name="Date_de_fin" />
</div>
</form>
<br></br>


<form method="post" action='#'>
<div class="test">
  <input type="submit" name="test" id="test" value="test"/>
 </div>
  </form>
 <?php

if(isset($_POST['test']))
    {
       if (! empty($_POST['date_deb_filtre']) and (! 
      empty($_POST['date_fin_filtre'])))
         {

      echo ($_POST['Date_de_debut']);
      echo ($_POST['Date_de_fin']);

          }

        }
    ?>


    </body>
   </html>
```

When I press the test button, the two dates did not appear on the page, can u guys help me with this

Comment: Where's the **value** attribute of your inputs ?

Comment: you need to convert `id` to `name` or use `name` attribute value in `$_POST`

Comment: @teeyo i addes a value but nothing has changed

Comment: @WadiBenRhouma your `date_deb_filtre` and `date_fin_filtre` are in the wrong form (it doesnt get sent with your test button). Shital's answer fixes it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
  <html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
    <link rel ="stylesheet" href="style_wbr.css"/>
    <title>PORTAIL</title>
</head>
<body>

<br></br>
<br></br>
<br></br>
  <form method = "post" >
   <div id="date">
  <input type="date" id="date_deb_filtre" name="Date_de_debut" />
  <input type="date" id="date_fin_filtre" name="Date_de_fin" />
</div>

<div class="test">
  <input type="submit" name="test" id="test" value="test"/>
 </div>
  </form>
 <?php

if(isset($_POST['test']))
    {
       if (!empty($_POST['Date_de_debut']) && (!empty($_POST['Date_de_fin'])))
         {

      echo $_POST['Date_de_debut'];
      echo $_POST['Date_de_fin'];

          }

        }
    ?>


    </body>
   </html>
```

There are silly mistakes is your code which is like you use two forms for single process and second that you can get value for input field through post method by name not by id.,try using this code this will work.

Comment: it works , i want also to add the results of the 'echo' function to an sql query , is it possible ?? and how can i concatenate it??

Comment: Yes you can add insert query and assign your $_POST variable in the dedicated field.,it's kind of a rookie question i'll prefer you to search over google you can find your query through that.cheers.

Comment: it's not that simple, it's a complicated query with a lot of joins , i tried to excute it bua there's an error of connexction , despite i use the same configuration , and it works in others code, i doubt that there  is something wrong with the query

Comment: try to run the query in database itself with raw inputs if it works then just copy the query in your code and replace raw data into dynamic variables,

Comment: php is only plays role to transfer your query to the database.

Answer (score 4):

remove extra form tag before test class and use  **if (!empty($_POST['Date_de_debut']) && !empty($_POST['Date_de_fin']))** in php

```
<?php
if(isset($_POST['test']))
{
     if (!empty($_POST['Date_de_debut']) && !empty($_POST['Date_de_fin']))
     {

        echo ($_POST['Date_de_debut']);
        echo ($_POST['Date_de_fin']);

      }
}
?>
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
    <link rel ="stylesheet" href="style_wbr.css"/>
    <title>PORTAIL</title>
</head>
<body>

<br></br>
<br></br>
<br></br>
  <form method = "post" action = "#">
    <div id="date">
      <input type="date" id="date_deb_filtre" name="Date_de_debut" />
      <input type="date" id="date_fin_filtre" name="Date_de_fin" />
    </div>
    <br></br>
    <div class="test">
    <input type="submit" name="test" id="test" value="test"/>
    </div>
  </form>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: @Shital Marakana tnks , it worked
but what did u mean by "tag"??

Comment: both are same && and "and" but  if (! empty($_POST['date_deb_filtre']) and (! empty($_POST['date_fin_filtre'])))

name is incorrect.

Answer (score 0):

You are submitting second form in which only this tag exist

```
<input type="submit" name="test" id="test" value="test"/>
```

Just remove the second form..

```
<html>
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
        <link rel ="stylesheet" href="style_wbr.css"/>
        <title>PORTAIL</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <br></br>
        <br></br>
        <br></br>
        <form method = "post" action = "#">
            <div id="date">
                <input type="date" id="date_deb_filtre" name="Date_de_debut" />
                <input type="date" id="date_fin_filtre" name="Date_de_fin" />
            </div>
            <br></br>
            <div class="test">
                <input type="submit" name="test" id="test" value="test"/>
            </div>
        </form>
    </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Here you should use `name` attribute instead of `id` of `input` tag on if else statement.

Replace this
`empty($_POST['date_deb_filtre'] , empty($_POST['date_fin_filtre']` with
`empty($_POST['Date_de_debut'] ,  empty($_POST['Date_de_fin']`

Here is your corect code :

```
<html>
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
    <link rel ="stylesheet" href="style_wbr.css"/>
    <title>PORTAIL</title>
</head>
<body>
    <br></br>
    <br></br>
    <br></br>
    <form method = "post" action = "#">
        <div id="date">
            <input type="date" id="date_deb_filtre" name="Date_de_debut" />
            <input type="date" id="date_fin_filtre" name="Date_de_fin" />
        </div>
    </form>
    <br></br>
    <form method="post" action='#'>
        <div class="test">
            <input type="submit" name="test" id="test" value="test"/>
        </div>
    </form>
     <?php
        if(isset($_POST['test'])) {
            //echo '<pre>'; print_r($_POST); echo '</pre>'; exit;
            if (! empty($_POST['Date_de_debut']) and (! empty($_POST['Date_de_fin']))) {
                echo ($_POST['Date_de_debut']);
                echo ($_POST['Date_de_fin']);
            }
        }
    ?>
</body>
```

OR You can Try this:

```
<html>
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
    <link rel ="stylesheet" href="style_wbr.css"/>
    <title>PORTAIL</title>
</head>
<body>
    <br></br>
    <br></br>
    <br></br>
    <form method = "post" action = "#">
    <div id="date">
    <input type="date" id="date_deb_filtre" name="Date_de_debut" />
    <input type="date" id="date_fin_filtre" name="Date_de_fin" />
    </div>
    <div class="test">
    <input type="submit" name="test" id="test" value="test"/>
    </div>
    </form>
    <br></br>
    <?php
        if(isset($_POST['test']))
        {
            //echo '<pre>'; print_r($_POST); echo '</pre>'; exit;
            if (! empty($_POST['Date_de_debut']) and (! empty($_POST['Date_de_fin']))) {
                echo ($_POST['Date_de_debut']);
                echo ($_POST['Date_de_fin']);
            }
        }
    ?>
</body>
```